# DIR_COLORS customization

Tags: linux, unix, ls

I am customizing my DIR_COLORS (~/.dir_colors) to colorize ls on my terminal.

I get how to change colors of files whose names ends in a known extension:

```
.cpp 0;34
```

But I would like to set colors for files with a fixed name like `Makefile` and `Kconfig`, and I would also like to change colors of files that begins with a dot (like `.config`), or some other pattern.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do it using `dircolors`, unfortunately.
One way to cope with single files like `Makefile` or `Kconfig` is to use:

```
*Makefile 00;36
```

Unfortunately, this colors everything which ends with `Makefile`, not just `Makefile`.
Coloring files which start with a particular prefix is probably impossible.

Comment: was just typing in my answer `export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}*Makefile=1;35"` as I read yours. +1